# CORS制限を通り抜けてTwitterのデータを取得するには

Tags: twitter

Twitterの過去のLikeやRTをランダムに表示するWebサービスを作ろうとしてるのですが、調べてみるとCORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)制限というのでブラウザ上で動くjavascriptでは別ドメイン(twitter)のデータにはアクセスできないようなんですがこれを回避する方法はないでしょうか？

あるいは、バックエンドでやるしかない場合どのようなサービス（Herokuなど）、言語がオススメでしょうか？（最初Firebaseを検討してましたが任意のコードを実行できるようではないようなので）

Comment: 言語のおすすめだと頂いた情報だけだと多少質問の範囲が広い印象があります。もう少し技術的背景やご自身のスキル情報もあるといいかなと思います。またtwitterapiの利用は可能ですか？

Comment: 開発経験はJavaでバックエンドならそれなりにあるのですがWebサービスの開発は初めてです。 >twitterapiの利用は可能ですか 可能ですかというか、Javaではtwitter4jというライブラリを使って色々できますが、ブラウザ上でjavascriptで実行できないらしいと調べた段階です。

Comment: 作りたいWebサービスですが、過去のLikeやRTをランダムに表示したいのでjavascriptでやるならOAuth認証してLike一覧、過去のツイート一覧を取得できればいい感じです。

Comment: おそらくどの言語を選択してもWebサービスの利用することになるとは思いますので、そこからですね。

Comment: 検索するとHerokuとかGoogle App Engineとか出てくるんですけどそこでもFirebaseがいいとか書いてあってちょっと混乱した状態です。twitterデータの取得自体はHerokuとかに置いたバックエンドでやってフロントエンドでは表示するだけという感じになると思うんですが特に決定打はない感じでしょうか？

Comment: まだどのような設計をなさろうとしてるのかイマイチぴんと来てないのですが、もしかしてスクレイピングっぽいことを考えてらっしゃいますか？　であればTwitterの[サービス利用規約](https://twitter.com/ja/tos)を一度読まれた方が良いかと思います。また、何故CORSが制限されているかはご存じでしょうか。おそらく Twitter API を使うことになるんじゃないかと今のところ思っています。

Comment: いえ、普通にTwitter APIを使うことを考えています。順を追って説明すると、Webサービスを作るにはVue＋Firebaseがいいと聞く→しかし調べてみるとブラウザ上のjavascriptでは外部へのアクセスができず、Firebaseではバックエンドで指定のコードを実行することはできないと知る→HerokuなどWebサービスを公開できるプラットフォームを検討することにしたが、どれがいいのかイマイチわからない。 という感じです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

フロントエンドからTwitter APIを取得することはできないということがわかったのでバックエンドで取得するようにしました。